# Mock from unittest not passed to Django view

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

```py
def test_student_get(admin_user, some_model_fixture):
    client = Client()
    request_with_cookies = set_cookie(client, admin_user[0])

    with patch('django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404') as mock_get_object_or_404:
        mock_get_object_or_404.side_effect = Http404

        response_from_view = client.get(
            reverse('student.get'),
            HTTP_REFERER=request_with_cookies.request['PATH_INFO'],
            data={'id': some_model_fixture.id},
            follow=True
        )
    assert response_from_view.status_code == 404
```

So, I'm writing some tests for my Django app, but I faced some problem:
I try to mock `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` func using `unittest`, it's successfully mocking in `test_student_get` function, but when my request goes up to view mocked func just disappearing and `mock_get_object_or_404` is behaving like usual, like it never been mocked.

My view:

```py
    try:
        value = get_object_or_404(SomeModel,id=id)
    except Http404:
        raise ApiError('Not found any obj', 404)
```

Also tried `@patch` decorator, same effect, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404 performs a query your_model.objects.all() and then filter by the arguments you sent.

So, to perform a patch you should do something like

```
@patch('path.to.your.model.YourModel.objects.all')
def test_get_object(self, mock_your_model)
    ...
```

Anyways I would recommend you to use something like

```
try:
    YourModel.objects.get(id=<id>)
except YourModel.DoesNotExist:
    raise ApiError('Not found any obj', 404)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Your problem is you mock the object where its defined, but where its defined is **not guarantee the real object** you use in your view.py.

You can see what document said in above link, here i will show you a simple example about this, you can try it :

```py
# in your view.py you can try 2 different import method
# we use requests library as an example

# first method
from requests import post

response = post("url")

#  second method
import requests

response = requests.post("url")
```

and try to mock these 2 post() (separate of course) in your test, either using patch() or patch.object()

```py
mock.patch("requests.post")
# or
mock.patch("path.to.view.post")
```

And you will figure out how exactly mock.patch() function.